# When using client-side encryption in a web application, where should keys be stored?

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, cryptography, webcrypto-api

Suppose I wanted to add client-side encryption to a web application using the JavaScript [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API). The client side of my application would encrypt each user's data using their key before sending the encrypted data to the server, and decrypt data returned by the server to show it.

How would users store their keys for an application like this, without making it inconvenient to use?

Is there some easy way to store the key in the browser?

Or would each user have to keep their key in a local file on their computer(s), and import it into the web app every time they log in? Could they use a separate password manager like Apple Keychain?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: its best not to store keys, but rather derive them from a password entered by the user. users can use a password manager if they don't want to type it in each time, but the key itself cannot be lost with the device.

Answer (score 4):

The breakthrough of the Web Cryptography Api is to provide native support to **creation, use and storage of cryptographic keys without exposing the content of private keys**

In summary:

1. Generate the keys using WebCrypto and mark them as non exportable
2. Store the key into IndexedDB

You can use the cryptographic key, but its contents will be hidden for both the user and the programmer. Note in the image that the 'cryptoKey' object is hidden by the browser

[image: Indexed DB with cryptographic key hidden]

**Why not use...**

- **Cookies / Local storage**: Only allow text storage. The key should be exported to a text format as base64 and its contents could be copied by a malicious agent or even the user...
- **Local File**: It is not at all user-friendly. The protection of the keys is completely in the hands of the user. Each application would require the user to import the key in WebCrypto.. This solution is not protected by same-origin policy. The user could use the key in other site.

**Alternatives** (comment by @dandavis)

- **Not store key** Derive a key from a password to be used with a symmetric encryption algorithm like AES. Key is derived when needed prompting the password to user. The advantage Using a password manager is possible, but then, the browser will have stored the password string. The key could be used from multiple computers

These solutions are suitable when the data must be hidden from the server. To let server process your client data you need (depending on the type of key)

- **symmetric keys:** you need to provide server with the key itself (so it has to be extractable), or the password in order to decrypt data
- **assymetric keys:** The server uses a keypair (public /private). The server send the public key to client. The data sent from client to server is encrypted with server public key and decrypted with private key. The data sent from server to client is encrypted with client public key and decrypted on with client private key.

Comment: how is indexedDB more secure than localStorage?

Comment: Keys are binary. To store into localStorage the key must be exported and converted to text format. Then it would not be protected by webcrypto. An attacker with access could extract the keys . With IndexedDB is not possible. Webcrypto keys can be stored directly without having to be exported and the contents are not visible

Comment: if the keys are available to malicious script, i don't see how visibility or storage format affects security, only obscurity. in short, if you can run code to use the keys, then so can an attacker. Firefox does have a built-in password storage mechanism (_like_ `prompt()`) on their crypto API, but i don't think that's what you're referring to...

Comment: No, I am not talking about Firefox. The biggest difference I see is that even with a malicious script, the attacker could hipothetically use your key, but he can not extract it out of your browser because private key is opaque. Check this interesting blog https://blog.engelke.com/2014/09/19/saving-cryptographic-keys-in-the-browser/

Comment: keys don't need extraction to hijack, but i supposes it adds _some_ margin of realistic protection, touchè.

Comment: the key to it is the mark them as non exportable. the root user can still see it, but now your Frenemy on the inside (of the webpage) can't either (government / rogue employee). i suppose it is like glitter for sunscreen, quite nice might work.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to save data in IndexedDB as completely non-extractable because IndexedDB operates on the client-side within the user's browser, and the data is accessible to the user and potential attackers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.